Pass argument to post_generation method - factory_boy
How to pass arguments from a factory's __init__ or .create() to post_generation in Factory Boy?
I have a Project factory, and I want to pass an argument (like num_participants) from the factory's __init__ or .create() method to the post_generation method, but I’m encountering an issue. Here's my code:
class FullProjectFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        exclude = ("num_participants",)  # Added a comma for tuple

    num_participants = 1
    name = Sequence(lambda n: f"full_test_project_{n}")

    @post_generation
    def create_related_objects(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        if not create:
            return

        # Trying to pass num_participants
        ParticipantFactory.create_batch(self.num_participants, project=self)

# Creating the project with a specific number of participants
p = FullProjectFactory.create(num_participants=10)

However, I get the following error:
ParticipantFactory.create_batch(self.num_participants, project=self)
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Project' object has no attribute 'num_participants'

How can I properly pass the num_participants argument to the post_generation method?

Solution
Managed to solve it on my own.
Solution is based on:
https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#extracting-parameters
class FullProjectFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Project

    name = Sequence(lambda n: f"full_test_project_{n}")

    @post_generation
    def create_related_objects(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        if not create:
            return
        
        num_participants = kwargs.pop('num_participants', 1)
        ParticipantFactory.create_batch(num_participants, project=self)

And:
p = FullProjectFactory.create(create_related_objects__num_participants=10)

